# Avoid breadcrumbs in method argument

Tags: python, recursion

A (python) method traverses files recursively and must capture missing files. I've come up with this:

```
def find_recursively(fname, breadcrumbs, missing_files):
   try:
       txt = read(fname)
   except FileNotFoundError:
       missing_files.add((breadcrumbs.copy(), fname))
       return

   next_files = analyze(txt)
   for fn i next_files:
       find_recursively(fn, breadcrumbs + [fname], missing_files)

missing_files = []
breadcrumbs = []
find_recursively('first_file.txt', breadcrumbs, missing_files)
```

But I wonder if there is a smarter way such that I can avoid polluting the arguments with `breadcrumbs` and `missing_files`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `analyze(txt)` is undefined if `read(fname)` raises an exception.

Comment: @chepner thanks. I added a return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chepner's solution was a breakthrough. Actually it is not necessary with breadcrumbs/missing_files arguments since missing_files can be returned and prepended with current file in the for(..) loop.

As a bonus I also realized that I can add a function pointer argument to increase reusability.

```
def traverse_includes_in_header(fn, do_stuff):
    # list of [breadcrumb 1..breadcrumb N, fn]
    missing_files = []
    try:
        txt = read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return [[fn]]

    includes = find_includes(txt)
    do_stuff(txt)
    for i in includes:
        mfs = traverse_includes_in_header(i, do_stuff)
        # prepend fn to every found missing file
        missing_files += [[fn] + mfl for mfl in mfs]

    return missing_files
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of `missing_files` by having your function *return* a list of breadcrumb/missing-file pairs. `breadcrumbs` doesn't appear to need a name outside of the function, and can be initialized using a default argument value. Having it be an argument is a *feature*, not something to be eliminated.

```
def find_recursively(fname, breadcrumbs=None):
   if breadcrumbs is None:
       breadcrumbs = []

   try:
       txt = read(fname)
   except FileNotFoundError:
       # No copy is really needed, because we always pass a new
       # list on the recursive call, and never *modify*
       # the list we receive.
       return [(breadcrumbs, fname)]

   next_files = analyze(txt)
   new_breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs + [fname]
   return [mf for fn in next_files for mf in find_recursively(fn, new_breadcrumbs)]

missing_files = find_recursively('first_file.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks. You inspired me to get rid of the breadcrumb argument by simply returning a list of missing files and add fn to each member as it is collected. See my answer below